# JQuery UI draggable, updating the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to append draggable items to an area. That's easy. The issue is that the DOM doesn't seem to be up to date.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxQxJN?editors=0010

The issue:
- Append first element, drag that element to the bottom on the area.
- Append a second element. It is positioned relative, but instead of appearing at the top of the area as expected it appears below where the first element *was*. It's like a ghost.

Any ideas how I can get the DOM to update so that the appended elements appear as expected?

```js
$('.addWidget').click( (event) => {
  let new_widget = `
    <div class="widget_container draggable" style="height: 130px; width: 260px;">
      <div class="widget">
         <b>Amazing widget</b>
         <p>My cool blah blah blah</p>
      </div>
    </div>`;
  
    $('main').append(new_widget);
    $(".draggable").draggable({
      containment: 'parent',
      snap: true,
      grid: [72, 72]
    });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: #ccc;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #efefef;
}
.pane_content_dimension_list {
    float:right;
    list-style: none;
    width: 10rem;
}

.pane_content_dimension_list .btn {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.page_view {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 4px 2px #aaa;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 792px;
    width: 612px;
}

.page_view main {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 18px;
    width: 100%;
}

.widget_container {
    padding:9px;
}

.widget {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 2px #eee;
    color: #939598;
    font-size: 8px;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 11px;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pane_content_dimension_list">
    <li id="campaign_goals" class="btn addWidget">Campaign Goals</li>
    <li id="flight_dates" class="btn addWidget">Flight Dates</li>
    <li id="key_findings" class="btn addWidget">Key Findings</li>
    <li id="mindsets" class="btn addWidget">Mindsets</li>
    <li id="targeting_notes" class="btn addWidget">Targeting</li>
</ul>
<div class="page_view">
  <main>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: _"It is positioned relative"_ then set them to have an absolute position

Comment: Your issue is related to the position of the element appended... try something like float right or give them a position calculated by your code, something like appending elements with incrementing coordinates (top, left).

Comment: JQuery UI is doing that. Positioning absolute breaks draggable. Even if it didn't the math involved in ensuring the element lands on the grid and not on any other elements would be pretty complex. Two elements is easy, but once there are seven there, adding an eighth is tougher.